# Wrap value in twisted deferred

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

There is function which must return a deferred object, but I get a value synchronously.

Now I am returning that value with `inlineCallbacks` decorator:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def collect(self, config):
    yield
    data = new_data() # synchronous call
    defer.returnValue(data)
```

But may be there is some function which wraps value in deferred object, which than is immediately called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`twisted.internet.defer.maybeDeferred`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.maybeDeferred.html)

Comment: return maybeDeferred(new_data) ?

Comment: I recommend the twisted users mailing list. People there are helpful. Also, btw, the documentation is generally excellent. If you look on the Twisted home page you'll find links to the official docs AND external tutorials, including an amazingly thorough tutorial by David Peticolas. I cannot recommend that tutorial enough.

Comment: Thank you. But I prefer SO to mailing lists, because it is a lot faster and more universal. I think each major project should run a support here :) (for example author of boto package often answers boto questions here). 

As for Twisted docs and manual by David Peticolas I also totally agree with you. Someday I would dive into twisted more deeply, but now dedlines are coming, so I am in a rush a little bit.